# Facebook App using Phonegap (Cordova JS)

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

We are working in Iphone app developement using Phonegap(Cordova JS).

We found some challenges in handling Facebook app in Iphone.

While running the app in simulator we found the following error.

"SECURITY WARNING: Please treat the URL above as you would your password and do not share it with anyone"

We tried to solve this issue by

1. Go to Face book account
2. Go to Privacy Setting
3. Click on Security tag on left side of Page
4. Then Disable Secure browsing

But we didn't get any fruitful solution to handle it.